# Get all Apache Spark executor logs

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to collect all the executor logs in the Spark application driver programmatically. (When something failed I want to collect and store all the relevant logs.) Is there a nice way to do this?

One idea is to create an empty RDD with one partition per executor. Then I somehow ensure that each partition is actually processed on a different executor (no idea how) and do a `mapPartitions` in which I load the executor log from disk, and then a `collect` to fetch them to the application.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps there is a better way, but we use a script to sync executor logs to S3 every 5 seconds

```
#!/bin/sh
# This scripts syncs executor log files to S3.

while [[ $# > 1 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  case $key in
    -l|--log-uri)
        LOG_BUCKET="$2"
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown option: ${key}"
        exit 1;
  esac
  shift
done

set -u

JOB_FLOW_ID=$(cat /mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json | grep jobFlowId | sed -e 's,.*"\(j-.*\)".*,\1,g')

# Start background process that syncs every 5 seconds.
while true; do aws s3 sync /home/hadoop/spark/work ${LOG_BUCKET}/${JOB_FLOW_ID}/executors/`hostname`/; sleep 5; done &
```

We launch the script (which is stored on S3 in a file named sync-executor-logs.sh) in a bootstrap action

```
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://path/to/my/script/sync-executor-logs.sh,Name=Sync-executor-logs,Args=[-l,s3://path/to/logfiles]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution! Nowadays we mostly run on YARN, and YARN provides some handling for the log files. While I haven't fully figured out how to configure it, it has also solved many of our problems.